# Searching Newton-Raphson failures!!

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I came up with a numerical method to find roots for nonlinear functions. Now I'm trying to see how better from other methods is. So.... where does Newton-Raphson fail? I came up with a function $f(x)=2{e}^{-x^{2}}-1$, that does not converge using N-R. The reason is that the derivative is very close to 0 value for most x. I think this happens to any function that asymptotically approcaches constant value. Others?

Comment: A lot of other functions do not work very well with this algorithm. Generally speaking, if your 2nd derivative doesn't change sign and is close to a constant then N-R is not too bad.

Comment: N-R can also fail because it falls into a loop. For example, consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x & x<-\frac 12\\-1-x&x > \frac 12\end{cases}$$ and between the two, crosses from one to the other smoothly. If you start N-R at any point $\notin \left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$, it will immediately start repeating $1, -1, 1, -1, \dots$.  One other way in which N-R fails is simply that in many practical applications, a derivative is not available. Practical root finders get around these and other limitations by monitoring convergence, and falling back on the bisection method when it fails.